# Is there any chance to upgrade my OpengGL version?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, upgrade, graphics, opengl

Here is my current OpenGL version: `string: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0`

Graphics: `Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset`

OS-type: `64-bit`

Laptop Brand: `ACER Aspire 4736z`

RAM: `2GB`

Ubuntu: `16.04 LTS`

Processor: `Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz × 2`

I already tried some of the things I saw in this website and did nothing.

Is there any chance that my OpenGL version upgrade at least 3.0? (That's what SuperTuxCart is asking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphics adapter does not support OpenGL higher than 2.1.

So it is a hardware, not a software issue.

Your adapter supports OpenGL 2.0 on Windows and 2.1 on Linux.

On my Bay Trail Intel adapter the same version of mesa shows

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
```

Comment: Oh, so sad, so I can't play any games with ubuntu now?

Comment: You can't play games that require OpenGL 3 on any OS, not only on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have any recommended games that can play with OpenGL 2? thanks.